# How to solve voltage dependant voltage sources in parallel to a resistor?

Tags: circuit-analysis, parallel

[image]

I just started learning about source transformation and came across this question. I get that I can replace the current sources with voltage sources in series along with the resistors in series as well. But what do I do about the the voltage dependant voltage source and resistor in parallel at the middle of the circuit? Turning the vdvs to current source wont help me since the resistor would still be in parallel. What am I missing?

Comment: are you certain that it is a `voltage dependant voltage source`?

Comment: It's current dependent current source

Comment: https://slideplayer.com/slide/6880670/23/images/82/Examples+of+Symbols+for+Controlled+%28Dependent%29+Sources.jpg

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a current dependent current source. If it's true you can replace it with a (11/2,3) Ohm resistor and the problem contains a kind of fool's trick.

It still needs some work to be solved after the replacement.

Assuming it's a voltage source with formula U=2,3Ix leads to a contradiction.

Comment: You mean 11/3,3

Comment: No, the current source should be replaced with (11/2,3) Ohms. Then there's still the 11 Ohm. I didn't claim anything about it. It stays or will be in the future combined with the (11/2,3 ) Ohm resistor.